# How to getTileProperty while using multi-layer map?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d, tiled

I'm new to Slick2D, and I'm using Tiled to make .tmx map.

```
for (int xAxis = 0; xAxis < map.getWidth(); xAxis++) {
    for (int yAxis = 0; yAxis < map.getHeight(); yAxis++) {
        int tileID = map.getTileId(xAxis, yAxis, 0);
        String value = map.getTileProperty(tileID, "blocked", "0");
        int valueInInt = Integer.parseInt(value);
        if (valueInInt == 1) {
            blocked[xAxis][yAxis] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when the blocks are on the same layer with others, however, if I put the blocks on a different Tile layer, I can't get the right TileProperty anymore.

Why did it happen? What can I do with that or any ideals?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter to [TiledMap.getTileId()](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/tiled/TiledMap.html#getTileId%28int,%20int,%20int%29) is the `layerIndex`. You would have to use that to select the layer where you're searching for tiles with the "blocked" property set to "1".